# IIS redirect from one subdomain to another

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config, subdomain

I need to set up rules to push a user from one subdomain if under a folder to another.  I need to move

- teststore.domain.edu/admin*
- devstore.domain.edu/admin*
- anysubdomain.domain.edu/admin*

to

- store.admin.domain.edu/admin

This works!

but I need to rewrite anything under

- **store.admin.domain.edu**

to

- store.admin.domain.edu/admin

and that doesn't, and really anything but

- store.admin.domain.edu/media*
- store.admin.domain.edu/js*
- store.admin.domain.edu/skin*
- store.admin.domain.edu/api*
- store.admin.domain.edu/admin/oauth_authorize*
- store.admin.domain.edu/index.php/admin*

would need to write redirect to

- store.admin.domain.edu/admin*

I almost have it but store.admin.domain.edu rewrites to devstore.domain.edu through a rule below as it was not caught.  I can't put anything in the rule below, it is generated.

```
<!-- RULES TO PUSH ADMIN TO SUBDOMAIN -->
<rule name="admin" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)"  ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="store.admin.domain.edu" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(.*?)/admin(.*?)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://store.admin.domain.edu/admin" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="admin_rooted" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)"  ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="store.admin.domain.edu" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(api|oauth_authorize|media|skin|js)" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^admin*" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^index.php/admin/*" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://store.admin.domain.edu/admin" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<!-- END OF RULES TO PUSH ADMIN TO SUBDOMAIN -->



<!-- rules that are generated -->
<rule name="default_store">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^devstore\.domain\.edu*" />
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
      <set name="HTTP_X_MAGE_RUN_CODE" value="base" replace="true" />
      <set name="HTTP_X_MAGE_RUN_TYPE" value="website" replace="true" />
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="general_rewrite">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(media|skin|js)/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" /> 
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

Comment: This is not clear what rule doesn't work. Can you add the input and expected output url?

Comment: I have edited the question, basicly the redirect to the •store.admin.domain.edu/admin if under store.admin.domain.edu* and not one of the listed is the part not working.

Comment: I have added an answer but wasn't able to test (and probably won't before Monday) but let me know if something doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your 2 rules to make them more simple:

```
<rule name="admin" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^admin" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^store.admin.domain.edu$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://store.admin.domain.edu/admin" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="admin_rooted" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(api|oauth_authorize|media|skin|js|admin|index.php/admin/)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^store.admin.domain.edu$" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://store.admin.domain.edu/admin" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The first rule will redirect any url starting with `admin` and not pointing to the host `store.admin.domain.edu` to `http://store.admin.domain.edu/admin`.

The second one will redirect any url that doesn't start with on of the following occurence: `api` or `oauth_authorize` or `media` or `skin` or `js` or `admin` or `index.php/admin/` pointing to the host `store.admin.domain.edu` and not being the path to a file or a directory to `http://store.admin.domain.edu/admin`.

Comment: Hello, I just tested it, but `admin_rooted` rule didn't move the user from `store.admin.domain.edu` to `store.admin.domain.edu/admin`, just went back to `devstore.domain.edu` which is the rooted subdomain for the rest.  As I see it, with the `stopProcessing="true"` that means that it's passed by this rule with no match to trigger for `store.admin.domain.edu` to make it redirect.

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC I have updated the rule in my answer. Let me know if it helped or not. (I removed 'admin' in the match url)

Comment: that removal just sent the url `store.admin.domain.edu/admin` into a redirect loop.  Everything else works but the match to the root `store.admin.domain.edu` to `store.admin.domain.edu/admin`

Comment: Is `admin` a directory under `store.admin.domain.edu`?

Comment: admin is not, it's a url rewrite, to index.php that is

Comment: What I meant is that you don't have a file/directory named `admin` inside your website root folder?

Comment: What if you go back with the first version I did write and try `store.admin.domain.edu/1`? Are all the rules from you `web.config` in your question?

Comment: no it still redirects back to the root of the site `devstore.domain.edu` and yes they are

Comment: I have a hard time understanding how it is possible. You have no rule redirecting to `devstore.domain.edu` so I don't understand where this behavior comes from. Your last rule called `general_rewrite` will be called in this case but it is a rewrite. Do we agree?

Comment: the redirect comes from the php script.  When it's not on one the right domain it will try to correct it's self.  That is start with the general rewrite for all to index.php.

Comment: In this case, `store.admin.domain.edu` will redirect you to `store.admin.domain.edu/admin` and then will trigger the rule called `general_rewrite` and this last one will redirect you to `devstore.domain.edu`. Am I correct? If yes, the rule works as expected but not as you do want it to work. What is this last rule suppose to do?

Comment: when you go to `store.admin.domain.edu/admin` it stays there and that is what I wanted.  when you go to `devstore.domain.edu` it is redirected to `store.admin.domain.edu/admin` and that is also what I wanted.  But when I go to `store.admin.domain.edu/` it goes down the rules & hits the general_rewrite rule which rewrites to the index.php for pretty urls.  The php looks at the urls thinks its not the right url & redirects you from  `store.admin.domain.edu/` to `devstore.domain.edu`.  If it's `store.` it shouldn't hit that last rule so index.php wouldn't process starting the redirect

Comment: So what you are saying is that when you hit `store.admin.domain.edu/admin` it works as expected but when you hit `store.admin.domain.edu/`, it doesn't redirect you to `store.admin.domain.edu/admin` and so, doesn't work as expected? If yes, can you try to remove in the `admin_rooted` rule the condition `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />`? Does the trailing `/` make a difference?

Comment: that was it.. so added back the admin to the `<match url="^(admin|api` removed the `/` in the '<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" ' on the rule `admin_rooted` and commented out that input and it's working now.  If you edit your answer so other will not get lost on the solution, and the cause for the failure then I'll mark it as the answer.  Thank you for the help.  Cheers

Comment: Not sure I get it sorry...commenting the `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />` did work by itself? Or did you change something else? (I reverted my answer to the first one so the `<match url="^(admin|api` is back here).

Comment: Your edit was not aproved so I did it. Thanks for the bounty!

Comment: odd , why was it not approved? but note, with that `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />` being removed, and the `admin` added back to the list being the solution, you also have a typo of and extra `>` in there.  Cheers

Comment: Reviewers believed you were trying to comment my answer and when I did try to do it, it didnt go through...should be OK now!